# X forwarding CUDA SDK application with OpenGL extensions

Tags: opengl, cuda, x11, nvidia, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to X forward a demo application from the CUDA SDK, but I get this error:

```
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
ERROR: Support for necessary OpenGL extensions missing.[oceanFFT] test results...
```

Other OpenGL applications like glxgears works fine.

Is it possible to X forward applications with this OpenGL extensions? If it is, how can I do this?

Comment: FWIW I've had a similar problem with VNC and running CUDA code.

Comment: The problem was also with OpenGL extensions? DId you manage to solve it?

Comment: I didn't really spend any time identifying the problem, other than to observe that CUDA code wouldn't run when I was connected to the target machine via VNC, although it would run fine when I was using the same machine directly - I presume there is some sort of interaction between the nVidia drivers and whatever method is used to capture screen drawing. Of course this may be a totally unrelated problem - it just seems that it might have something in common with your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that not for all extensions GLX opcodes have been defined (for some reasons I cannot fathom). So you're out of luck, although I know of NVidia to have some private GLX opcodes they use to implement forwarding for some OpenGL extensions, where it hasn't been fully specified.

I'm actually thinking of implementing some kind of private "GLX3" X.org extension module and accompanying libGL3.so, for purely indirect rendering then. However since OpenGL-3 has a strong focus on using Buffer Objects, i.e. keeping the bandwidth utilization low, there's not much harm in purely indirect operation these days. Old OpenGL-2 with client side vertex arrays, that was a bandwidth hog.